# Java 8u40 Swing GUI performance

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have an application that's presenting *very* complex Swing GUI. GUI contains total of about 60 000 different controls (mostly labels, less text fields). Basically, it's a table where each of many cells contains a stand alone control with few labels and a text box.

The problem i'm suddenly having is related to java releases after (and including) 8u40. Project is built using JDK 8u122. When i run my application using Java 8u31, everything works fine and smooth. When i run my application using any Java (JRE) past 8u31, application starts rendering my complex controls, then soon takes 100% CPU and it all blocks, i have to kill my app.

Why's that? I was checking patch notes for 8u40 but i wasn't able to find anything that could cause such a big slowdown.

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Have you access to a Profiler? In such an extreme case, a profiler might lead you in the right direction to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: You mean JProfile? I Tried "VisualVM" but as soon as CPU usage hits 100% VisualVM becomes unresponsive as well. I also checked beta version, u155 and same thing happens. Checking further, i stumbled upon this unresolved bug. Maybe it's related... https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091556

Comment: JProfiler, YourKit, VisualVM, there are a number of Java Profilers available. That bug is about JavaFX, you write of a Swing UI. If the profiler becomes unresponsive, it is often due to garbage collection going on in the profiled application (stop the world phase). You might try to do some GC logging to see if this is the problem. Or compare the memory usage of 8u31 with 8u40+ before it becomes unresponsive.

Comment: *"GUI contains total of about 60 000 different controls (mostly labels, less text fields)."* Maybe you should redesign the app. to only include a limited number of controls. *"Basically, it's a table.."* Do you mean a `JTable`? If done correctly, that will have (at maximum) as many controls as there are columns. They use the 'flyweight pattern' for rendering things like a `JTable`, which means one control will be used to render that cell in every row.

Comment: (long time ago) I remmenber about very similair problem (`> Java6_25` and `<Java6_31` ??? or `<Java6_32`???) every Swing based aplications with inmemory db and SwingWorker caused similair lacks, no idea about problem(s) but newer versions never ever ..., without/any help, track, report in sun_bug

Comment: @Cello: i do call System.gc() at certain point to clean up the mess. Application never (even during the CPU trashing) takes more than 300 MB of ram (max allowed set to 1G). I'll try without GC to see if there will be any difference. I'm not very optimistic thou because i call GC after everything is done, things freeze in the middle of creating controls

Comment: @Andrew: No, i don't use JTable per sei. It's a JScrollPane with columns. Each column is a panel that contains rows of other controls. I need JScrollPane because of some other things. The main issue is that things even like that work perfectly under Java 8u31, but as soon as i try with 8u40 everything gets stuck... Not sure why...

Comment: @mKorbel: i had similar problems before on another place, but of the same nature in the same app. For example, in my app i also have a JPanel that's "simulating" a list - it's a JPanel, rather than JList because each "item" has to be a complex Swing control (with it's own layout) presenting some "preview" of underlying data. There were some Java 7 versions which simply refused that design (100% CPU). Anyway, my app i have to debug is a big, enterprise-size application that has to meaningfully present a lot of complex data which can't be described meaningfully only by simple text items

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` VM argument I'm using!

Without it, things work even on newer Java versions.

Now, with so many controls, I need `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`

Comment: I am confused, first you say it works without then you say you need it. What is it now?

Comment: Well custom control works without it, but takes 1GB of RAM :) With that VM argument (which worked fine up to Java 8u40) application keeps memory consumption to about 350 MB